# Is there a way to output the assembly of a single function in isolation?

Tags: gcc, assembly, compiler-construction, clang

I am learning how a C file is compiled to machine code. I know I can generate assembly from `gcc` with the `-S` flag, however it also produces a lot of code to do with `main()` and `printf()` that I am not interested in at the moment.

Is there a way to get `gcc` or `clang` to "*compile*" a function in isolation and output the assembly?

*I.e.* get the assembly for the following c in isolation:

```
int add( int a, int b ) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Some IDEs will let you set a breakpoint and view the assembly code generated by that function.  It's called the *disassembly window*. That should do what you're looking for - are you using an IDE?

Comment: I prefer to compile (with optimizations) then disassemble, you have to understand that the compiler will leave a few instructions incomplete for external addresses and such, but it is easier to read IMO than using -S.  gcc -O2 -c hello.c -o hello.o, objdump -D hello.o

Comment: Go here: http://gcc.godbolt.org/ paste the function, select the compiler, very useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two ways to do this for a specific object file:

1. The `-ffunction-sections` option to `gcc` instructs it to create a *separate ELF section* for each function in the sourcefile being compiled.
2. The symbol table contains section name, start address and size of a given function; that can be fed into `objdump` via the `--start-address`/`--stop-address` arguments.

The first example:

```
$ readelf -S t.o | grep ' .text.'
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000040
  [ 4] .text.foo         PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000040
  [ 6] .text.bar         PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000060
  [ 9] .text.foo2        PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000000c0
  [11] .text.munch       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000110
  [14] .text.startup.mai PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000180
```

This has been compiled with `-ffunction-sections` and there are four functions, `foo()`, `bar()`, `foo2()` and `munch()` in my object file. I can disassemble them separately like so:

```
$ objdump -w -d --section=.text.foo t.o

t.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text.foo:

0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
   4:   8b 3d 00 00 00 00       mov    0(%rip),%edi        # a <foo+0xa>
   a:   31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
   c:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   e:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  13 <foo+0x13>
  13:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  15:   75 01                   jne    18 <foo+0x18>
  17:   90                      nop
  18:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  1c:   c3                      retq
```

The other option can be used like this (`nm` dumps symbol table entries):

```
$ nm -f sysv t.o | grep bar
bar       |0000000000000020|   T  |    FUNC|0000000000000026|     |.text
$ objdump -w -d --start-address=0x20 --stop-address=0x46 t.o --section=.text

t.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000020 <bar>:
  20:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  24:   8b 3d 00 00 00 00       mov    0(%rip),%edi        # 2a <bar+0xa>
  2a:   31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
  2c:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  2e:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  33 <bar+0x13>
  33:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  35:   75 01                   jne    38 <bar+0x18>
  37:   90                      nop
  38:   bf 3f 00 00 00          mov    $0x3f,%edi
  3d:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  41:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   46 <bar+0x26>
```

In this case, the `-ffunction-sections` option *hasn't* been used, hence the start offset of the function isn't zero and it's not in its separate section (but in `.text`).

Beware though when disassembling object files ...

This isn't *exactly* what you want, because, for object files, the `call` targets (as well as addresses of global variables) aren't resolved - you can't see here that `foo` calls `printf`, because the resolution of that on binary level happens only at link time. The assembly source would have the `call printf` in there though. The information that this `callq` is actually to `printf` is in the object file, but separate from the code (it's in the so-called *relocation* section that lists locations in the object file to be 'patched' by the linker); the disassembler can't resolve this.

Comment: I see, just fyi for anyone else, you can use "gcc -ffunction-sections -c test.c" to compile a source file to an object file. Thanks~

Answer (score 2):

The best way to go would be to copy your function in a single `temp.c` C file and to compile it with the `-c` flag like this: `gcc -c -S temp.c -o temp.s`

It should produce a more tighten assembly code with no other distraction (except for the header and footer).